# HTML/CSS - Semi-Transparent background of div? With Scrollbar next to it

Tags: html, css, transparency

Hello i am looking for solution to do that:
http://www.delightfulwoman.pl/depilacja-laserowa/

When you click on the link on the left, the text changes inside right box...
I just want to know how to make that CornerRounded SemiTransparent div background, with scrollbar NEXT to it, not inside it.

You would say i can look into source file, but i am not that good at CSS, and i cant see transparency or opacity there :s or anything similar.

Comment: Your example uses a semi-transparent `.png` background image and the CSS property `overflow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website is using an image as the background for that DIV. They are using a PNG file which supports transparency. So in the CSS for the DIV (.o_right_cont) they are using an image of a rounded and translucent box instead of any fancy CSS.

On the inside of that DIV they have another DIV (.ofe_desc). They set the overflow to auto so that way the scrollbar would appear when the content is larger than the DIV.

```
 .o_right_cont {
        background: url(gfx/cennik_bg.png) no-repeat;
        width: 670px;
        height: 420px;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0px 0px 30px;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    .ofe_desc {
        width: 662px;
        height: 400px;
        text-align: left;
        overflow: auto;
        line-height: 15px;
        padding: 8px 30px 8px 8px;
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Kind Regards,
- Chris